# How do I append zeroes at the end of two combined fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have these 2 fields, SBSNBR, SEQNBR and I need to combine them into a 50 character length field. The total records of the two fields will be 11 in total and I want the remaining to populated with zeroes. Below is an example of the expected output.

Characters are left justified so it would look like this:

> 12345678900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: Maybe STUFF can do this?   For sure you can do it with LEFT(SBSNBR+SEQNBR+'(a string of 50 zeros)',50).

Comment: Post what you've tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [LEFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) function.

```
SELECT LEFT(SBSNBR+SEQNBR+'00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',50)
FROM Table
```

Comment: thanks I believe that's correct but I am getting ambiguous column name error but that may be more on the srver side

Comment: @khan16 That happens when you're trying to select from a column that exists on two different tables. You'll need to alias it or rename it.